# Coded UI Test is slow waiting for UI thread

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I've added Coded UI Tests to my ASP.NET MVC solution in Visual Studio 2013.  I was dismayed to see how slowly the tests run; each page just sits there for up to a minute or more before the test machinery wakes up and starts filling in the form fields.

After some experimentation (including turning off `SmartMatch`), I've discovered that simply calling

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
```

solves the problem.  But, as expected, the test frequently fails because the UI thread isn't ready for the test machinery to interact with the controls on the form.

Calling

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
```

makes the test run reliably, if slowly.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  Any hope that someone might have some insight into the magic baked into the WaitForReady machinery?  Are there any other settings related to WaitForReady that I can fiddle with besides `WaitForReadyLevel`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I've worked out what appears to be a combination of settings that allows my Coded UI Tests to reliably run at full speed -- faster than I could interact with the website by hand.

Note: The relevant "documentation" (if you call a blog "documentation") can be found here:

- [Playback configuration settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/08/10/configuring-playback-in-vstt-2010.aspx)
- [Retrying failed playback actions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/20/retrying-failed-playback-actions-with-coded-ui.aspx).

The trick requires several modifications to the default playback settings:

- Setting `WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled` allows the test to run at full speed.  But it also disables the (slow!) magic that waits until it's safe to interact with controls on the page.
- Setting a `MaximumRetryCount` and attaching an error handler deals with most of the errors that result from disabling the "wait for ready" magic.  Because I've baked a 1 second `Sleep` into the retry logic, this value is effectively the number of seconds I'm willing to wait for the page to load and become responsive.
- Apparently, failure to find the control under test is not one of the errors handled by the error handler/retry mechanism.  If the new page takes more than a few seconds to load, and the test is looking for a control that doesn't exist until the new page loads, the test fails to find the control and the test fails.  Setting `ShouldSearchFailFast = false` solves that problem by giving you the full timeout time for your page to load.
- Setting `DelayBetweenActions = 500` appears to work around a problem that I see occasionally where the UI misses a button click that occurs immediately after a page has loaded.  The test machinery seems to think that the button was clicked, but the web page doesn't respond to it.
- The "documentation" says that the default search timeout is 3 minutes, but it's actually something greater than 10 minutes, so I explicitly set `SearchTimeout` to 1 second (1000 ms).

To keep all of the code in one place, I've created a class that contains code used by all of the tests.  `MyCodedUITests.StartTest()` is called by the `[TestInitialize]` method in each of my test classes.

This code really should be executed only once for all of the tests (rather than once per test), but I couldn't figure out a way to get the `Playback.PlaybackSettings` calls to work in the `[AssemblyInitialization]` or `[ClassInitialization]` routines.

```
/// <summary> A class containing Coded UI Tests. </summary>
[CodedUITest]
public class UI_Tests
{
    /// <summary> Common initialization for all of the tests in this class. </summary>
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        // Call a common routine to set up the test
        MyCodedUITests.StartTest();
    }

    /// <summary> Some test. </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        this.UIMap.Assert_HomePageElements();
        this.UIMap.Recorded_DoSomething();
        this.UIMap.Assert_FinalPageElements();
    }
}


/// <summary> Coded UI Test support routines. </summary>
class MyCodedUITests
{
    /// <summary> Test startup. </summary>
    public static void StartTest()
    {
        // Configure the playback engine
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.MaximumRetryCount = 10;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ShouldSearchFailFast = false;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions = 500;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 1000;

        // Add the error handler
        Playback.PlaybackError -= Playback_PlaybackError; // Remove the handler if it's already added
        Playback.PlaybackError += Playback_PlaybackError; // Ta dah...
    }

    /// <summary> PlaybackError event handler. </summary>
    private static void Playback_PlaybackError(object sender, PlaybackErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // Wait a second
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Retry the failed test operation
        e.Result = PlaybackErrorOptions.Retry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your own post.  This sped up my tests tremendously.

Comment: This fixed pretty much everything for me. I still have some timing issues with some Async operations that go on, but that is to be expected. Thanks!

Comment: did anyone ever got this working with running the test cases based on [AssemblyInitialization] .  For what i'm doing.  I need to run my test in [AssemblyInitialization].  I'm specifically talking about Playback.PlaybackSettings.  If someone got this working a quick answer or example would be great.  Tahnks

Answer (score 6):

Coded UI searches for controls on the screen and that search is quite fast if successful. However if the search fails then Coded UI has another try using a "smart match" method and that can be slow. The basic way of avoiding Coded UI falling back to using smart matching is to remove or simplify search items that may change from run to run.

[This Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dave_froslie/archive/2012/08/10/why-do-my-coded-ui-tests-pause-during-playback.aspx) gives lots of explanation of what happens and how to fix it. The example therein shows a speedup from 30 seconds to 8 seconds by changing a search string from

```
Name EqualsTo “Sales order‬ (‎‪1‬ - ‎‪ceu‬)‎‪ - ‎‪‪‪Sales order‬: ‎‪SO-101375‬‬, ‎‪‪Forest Wholesales”
```

to

```
Name Contains “Sales order‬ (‎‪1‬ - ‎‪ceu‬)‎‪ - ‎‪‪‪Sales order‬: ‎‪SO”
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer to the question asked.  The OP states that SmartSearch has already been turned off.  If a control can't be found reasonably efficiently, the test simply fails.  Moreover, experimentation has verified that the observed problem is related to the `WaitForReady` machinery.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is captured from microsoft dynamics tool. Please check the length of the string captured from inspect tool. You will be finding some hidden character. just order‬ (‎‪1‬ - ‎‪ceu‬)‎‪. Else just move the cursor from "(" to ")". You will be finding cursor is not moving sometime when pressing right arrow key.