# Hand Coded UI script runs very slow

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using Coded UI to automate scripts. I am a newbie to C# and I was able to write a hand coded browser script in coded UI and the test passed, but the script execution is dead slow. I assume that some kind of threading has to be disabled. Could somebody please help to resolve the problem -Thanks, Kalaivani

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: [Coded UI Test is slow waiting for UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367855/coded-ui-test-is-slow-waiting-for-ui-thread)

Can you be more specific about what looks like (provide some code) and where it is slow (which methods are taking long time).

Also, have you compared the execution time of Debugging the test vs Running the test?